# Coffee is free/for free

Tags: grammar

1. Coffee is free.
2. Coffee is for free.

---

Which one is grammatical? Do you have some more similar expressions?

Answer (score 1):

"Coffee is free" is a general statement, but not a true one because sometimes coffee is not free (even if you are giving it away right now).  You could qualify the statement "Coffee is free in the staff common room."

"Coffee for free" is not a complete sentence. You could say "There is coffee for free." Or you could use "Coffee for free" as a slogan on a sign.

But the simplest slogan would be "Free Coffee!"

Answer (score 0):

"For free" is casual and idiomatic, according to strict grammarians.

[For free](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/for_free.htm)